# AdMob SDK and iOS 5

Tags: ios5, admob

I'm working on a lite version of my app in which I want to put AdMob's ads.

I have downloaded their SDK and followed their instructions, but I can't manage to show any ad in my app.
Also the [sample project](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/mobile/ads/docs/ios/fundamentals.html#result) they let you download seems to be broken.

(After compiling it, an empty view appear in the simulator.)

Anyone with a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen no specific issues with running AdMob ads with iOS 5.  Also, if you're using iAds in conjunction with AdMob, I wrote a small wrapper available on [github](https://github.com/larsacus/LARSAdController) that will handle both networks with as little as a single line of code. It's what I'm currently using in my apps, and I've seen no issue with it, even under iOS 5.  I tried to make the integration instructions as clear as I could to make it easy.

Answer (score 0):

The current iOS SDK, version 4.1.1, was not tested against iOS 5 as it was released a few months before iOS 5 was released.  An iOS 5 compatible SDK will be released very shortly.